# A determinant from analytic geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, determinant

I have a question regarding the following determinant:

$\begin{vmatrix}
+ax - by - cz & bx+ay & cx+az \\ 
bx+ay& -ax+by-cz & bz+cy \\
cx+az & bz+cy & -ax-by+cz
\end{vmatrix}
=
(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(x^2 + y^2 +z^2)(ax+by+cz).$

I can prove the above equality by performing row operations and column operations. However the above equation has a lot of geometrical terms and it seems to me that this equation could have other interpretations that I am missing.

So I have two questions:

1) Can we write the given determinant as product of two determinants (or three even)?

2) Is there a conceptual proof of the above equality through linear algebra or analytic geometry?

Comment: Right hand side is $||(a, b, c)||^2 ||x, y, z||^2  ((a, b, c) \cdot (x, y, z) )$ for Euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb R^3$. So, for example, your determinant computes $\langle ||m||^2 m, ||n||^2 n \rangle$ for pair of vectors. Maybe some intricate shenanigans with cross products can give you something, but it doesn't seem like something very interesting.

Comment: Why do you think it is not interesting? Do you mean that the associated matrices might be very messy?

Comment: Any context on where this comes from? Trying to factor a matrix without other information is a bit rough...

Comment: No, thats the problem. It comes from a set of problems on determinants. :(

Comment: Treat the determinant as a polynomial in $a,b,c,x,y,z$. Note that if $a=b=c=0$, then the matrix determinant is zero. Similarly, if $x=y=z=0$, then the matrix determinant is zero. This tells you why $a^2+b^2+c^2 $ and $x^2+y^2+z^2$ are roots of the determinant, because if these are zero, then the determinant is also zero. There is still a linear term left, so you should see how , if $ax+by+cz=0$, then with no other restrictions the determinant is zero. Then, by comparison of degrees, up to a constant the equality is verified. I don't know the first part, though.

Comment: Possibly useful :  Can be written as the sum of outer products : $\begin {bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} x & y & z\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\end{bmatrix} - \langle (a, b, c)~ | ~(x, y, 
    z) \rangle I_ 3 $

Comment: Thank you erfink. I solved the problem using your representation, some 3 d geometry and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the answer to the first question. But the problem can be solved by using linear algebra.

---

**Proof:**
Define $u = (a,b,c)$, $v = (x,y,z)$ and $P = uv^T + vu^T$[Thanks erfink].The given problem asks us to prove the following: $$\det(P - (u^Tv)I) = ||u||^2 ||v||^2 u^Tv.$$

We note that $P$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and we make the following observations:

1. $w = u \times v$ is in the null space of $P$ since $v^Tw = u^Tw=0$. So zero is an eigenvalue.
2. We can assume that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ because of homogeneity.
3. Since we may assume $||u|| = ||v|| = 1$, it follows that $(uv^T + vu^T)(u+v) = (u^Tv + 1)(u+v)$, $(uv^T+vu^T)(u-v) = (u^Tv -1)(u-v).$ Thus $u^Tv + 1$, $u^Tv-1$ are eigenvalues of $P$ as well.

From these observation it follows that the characteristic polynomial is $$t(t+1-u^Tv)(t-1-u^Tv) = \det(tI - P).$$

Substituting $t = u^Tv$, we get $$u^Tv = \det(P - (u^Tv)I).\blacksquare$$

Comment: Glad that those helped! I think that there's still something in there with being able to write the given matrix as a "nice" product of a matrix with its transpose, but it is still escaping me. The Cholesky Decomposition isn't particularly nice, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can answer the first question. We can write the matrix as a product of two rectangular matrices.

$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
+ax - by - cz & bx+ay & cx+az \\ 
bx+ay& -ax+by-cz & bz+cy \\
cx+az & bz+cy & -ax-by+cz
 \end{matrix}\right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
a & -b & c & 0\\ 
b & a & 0 & -c \\
c & 0 & -a & b \\
 \end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
x & y & z\\ 
y & -x & 0\\
-z & 0 & x\\
0 & z & -y\\
 \end{matrix}\right] = A^TB$$

The determinant can be evaluated using [Cauchy-Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) formula:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & -b & c & 0\\ 
b & a & 0 & -c \\
c & 0 & -a & b \\
 \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}
x & y & z\\ 
y & -x & 0\\
-z & 0 & x\\
0 & z & -y\\
 \end{vmatrix}= |A^TB|= A_{123}B_{123}+A_{124}B_{124}+A_{134}B_{134}+A_{234}B_{234}.$$

where $A_{ijk}$ stands for the determinant of the matrix formed by rows $i,j,k$.

Now just verify that 
$$A_{123}B_{123}=ax(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
$$A_{124}B_{124}=by(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
$$A_{134}B_{134}=cz(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
$$A_{234}B_{234}=0.$$